# Meaning of the Black Bile

Tags: word-usage

In following sentence of Mario Puzo's novel "Godfather", there is a reference of word "black bile".
"The black bile, sourly bitter, rose in Bonasera's thought, overflowed through tightly clenched teeth. He used his white linen pocket handkerchief and held it against his lips"
What "black bile" really is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *The **black bile**, sourly bitter, **rose in Bonasera's thought**, overflowed through tightly clenched teeth. He used his white linen
>   pocket handkerchief and held it against his lips*

The metaphorical application of *[bile](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/bile)* in Bonasera's **thought**:

> 2 Anger; irritability:

It is possible that *black bile* suggests *deadly anger*, but the larger context may give you some hints about a more precise interpretation.

Answer (score 6):

Black bile refers back to the old medical theory of [Humorism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Humorism) (Wikipedia)

> Humorism, or humoralism, is a system of medicine detailing the makeup and workings of the human body, adopted by the Indian Ayurveda system of medicine, Ancient Greek and Roman physicians and philosophers, positing that an excess or deficiency of any of four distinct bodily fluids in a person — known as humors or humours — directly influences their temperament and health.

Specifically:

> **Black Bile:**
>   The word "melancholy" derives from Greek μέλαινα χολή (melaina kholé) meaning 'black bile', from the belief that an excess of black bile caused depression.

Comment: What will it be called in moder medical terms?

Comment: From Minds behind the Brain: [Today, black bile is the only humor not recognized as a physiological fluid. Most likely, the Greeks observed the darkening of certain bodily fluids in states of disease, and concluded that there must be a dark, turgid humor.](https://books.google.com/books?id=6HE8S6y8CLIC&pg=PA31&dq=%22black+bile%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=VHYVVYCnAcu8ggTy1oLYAg&ved=0CDwQ6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=%22black%20bile%22&f=false)